# Unilateral transfers in the balance of payments

Tags: macroeconomics, balance-of-payments

In the secondary income account, unilateral transfers like unconditional foreign aid are recorded but aren't every transaction double-entry to make the balance of payments equal 0. What is the other entry in the KAFA to account for these unilateral transfers?